# How to stop vim from automatically displaying latex formatting?

Tags: visual-mode, filetype-tex, conceal

I have a latex file I am editing in vim. Something annoying that I'm running into is that vim seems to auto display things that I am typesetting in math mode.

Here is an example. Say I write the code

$v^{2}$ and $V_{wind}>>V_{ocean}$

I would like it to simply display this way as it would in visual mode, but instead, I get something that looks like the output of latex code, except not quite working. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: do you have any latex plugins installed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160953/disable-latex-symbol-conversion-in-vim

Comment: huh TIL can't mark as duplicate when original was on a different SE network.

Comment: disable concealing: `:set conceallevel=0`